# CSS: Altering Font-Size of Paragraph changes Display Size of H1

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am working on the mobile version of a website and I've noticed that changing the font-size of a paragraph affects the display size of the h1 above it (even though the h1's font-size remains the same).

The css for the desktop version is:

```
div.introWrapper
{
    width:100%;
    min-height:400px;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

div.introWrapper h1
{
    font-size:32pt;
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:150px;
}

div.introWrapper p
{
    padding-left:20%;
    padding-right:20%;
}
```

And the css for the mobile version is:

```
div.introWrapper h1
{
    padding-left:120px;
    padding-right:120px;
    font-size:40pt;
}

div.introWrapper p
{
    font-size:18pt;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:140px;
    padding-right:140px;
}
```

At this setting, the website renders like this:

[image: expected]

However changing the font-size of the paragraph to 20pt (in the mobile css) causes the website to render like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/80K6Q.png]

I am not sure why changing the font-size of the paragraph would change the display size of the h1 above it. (and increase the display size of the paragraph by significantly more than 2pt)

I am testing this in Google Chrome on the Apple iPhone 4 device (320px by 420px).

Answer (score 2):

In the mobile CSS you are changing the `h1` font-size to `40pt`

Comment: Yes, I would like the h1 to be slightly larger on the Mobile version, but on both pictures provided the h1 is set to 40pt. The two pictures are variations of the mobile css, not a desktop to mobile comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Using `pt` as measurement unit for font-size on screen is not a good idea - pt measurement is intended for printing. So on a screen, a pt size will always depend on the screen resolution, which especially between a desktop screen and a mobile device can be drastically different. Use em or `px` measurement units instead for your font sizes.

Comment: I changed the h1 font-size to 4em, and the p font-size to 1.2em:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/zkjFZ.png

However changing the p font-size to 1.3em caused it to look like this:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/uMoi2.png

I am confused as to why changing the p font-size affects the display size of the h1, and why a font-size of 1.2 em causes the paragraphs to be barely readable and a 1.3 em font size to be significantly larger.

Comment: em sizes are relative and often inherited from parent or higher level elements. What you describe is probably caused by the settings of the elements (divs) *around* these p and h1 tags. You can also try to use "rem" as a unit, which is always relative to the root element (body or html). This might be unseful information: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've fiddled around with the font-sizes and it seems that whenever either size (h1 or p) exceeds around 2.2rem, both of them gain a massive jump in size. This is baffling me haha

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was a problem in Google Chrome's developer tool "device mode". The website rendered perfectly on my iPhone, but all sorts of *strange things*  happened when testing it in Google Chrome.

Thank you for your responses!